# Change admin password on Server 2012, breaks IIS

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have a server 2012 box running IIS.  I am trying to change the admin password for the OS, but it is breaking permissions/access for IIS.  I have since reverted back to the old password and all works.  What do I need to change in addition to the OS to make the new password work for IIS sites?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open IIS
2. Select **Application Pools**
3. right-click on your pool and select **Advanced settings...**
4. Edit the *Identity* setting with your credentials

For mine, I set the Custom Account. I have to update this every time I change my credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried synchronizing the new passwork in IIS, in the sites thats don't work?

Check site credentials, specially if using a "specific user" (as opposed to pass-through authentication) at:
IIS console-->Click on site-->Click Basic Settings (on the Action panel)-->Connect As

There you can synchronize the password registered in IIS with the current user password, but take note that if this works, then something is wrong with your configuration since the logged on user (the admin as you mentioned) shouldn't be used to access site data/folders. It's way too risky!!

If you're using pass-through authentication, check the configuration of the application pool that the site is using, but I repeat: If changing/synchronicing the admin's passwork solves your problem, then you must have some bad configuration in place.